# Complex form without javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to build a 1.0 version for a web application, and I want to build the first preview version without any javascript/ajax etc. which I plan to add later. I am having problems with little complicated forms that have many options. 
For example, if it was and order form where user could add and remove products, add and remove services, type in messages and check options but all on single page and in the submit the order. Now my problem is with keeping the form's state between the requests. 
What would be the best way to keep the form's viewmodel state? Lets say when user adds/removes a product to their orde
r would I have to pass the whole viewmodel to controller's AddProdcut()/RemoveProduct() method every time and then return the updated viewmodel? Any examples, links and advices would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I just discovered Session and TempData, are these apropriate for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebForm

what you do is create model for the form eg:
And add the information to ItemsToSave collection. that will be responsible to keep the data.

```
class FormModel{
 public bool Option1{get;set;}
 public string DeliveryLocation{get;set;}
 public IEnumerable<key,value> ItemsToSave{get;set;}
}
```

after 
In controller you do this

```
public partial FormController : controller.. {

//this part create blank view
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult StartForm(){
 return View( new FormModel());
}

[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StartForm(FormModel model){
if (!ModelState.IsValid) return model;

//and here do your saving logic.
}
}
```

}

Comment: That is pretty much how I do it, but the actual problem is how to keep the FormModel's objects state between requests and page reloads/redirects? Lets say someone add new Item to your ItemsToSave, and then they add one more item, and the delete some item, how would you keep the instance of your FormModel object keep track of all those changes?